# Unable to receive file data in FormCollection object inside controller

Tags: c#, jquery, .net, asp.net-mvc-4

I have following markup:

```
<form id="did" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <textarea name="description">Text</textarea>
    <input name="files" id="files" type="file" accept="doc,pdf" />
    ...
</form>
```

And in controller its like this:

```
  public int Edit_Submit(FormCollection oForm)
    {

            var attachedFiles = oForm["files"];
            var description= oForm["description"];
            ....
    }
```

I am posting the form through `jQuery` which look like this:

```
var formInfo = $("#did").serialize();
    $.post('../../data/SubmitEdit', formInfo, function (serverResult) {
   ...
```

I am receiving other data fine but always `null` in `attachedFiles`.

Is it not possible through this way? What am I doing wrong please help.

Comment: if you look at the source after selecting a file is there any data stored in the files input?  Its been a while but I believe that data is stored in an auto generated input next to the files input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think your uploaded file will be in your form collection.

Try something like this maybe:

```
<form id="did" action="../../data/SubmitEdit" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <textarea name="description">Text</textarea>
    <input name="files" id="files" type="file" accept="doc,pdf" />
    ...
</form>

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SubmitEdit(FormCollection oForm, HttpPostedFileBase files) {
     ...
```

Make sure `HttpPostedFileBase` name is the same as the `id` of your `input[type="file"]`

Answer (score 0):

`$.post()` method is essentially an ajax call, or in more technical terms, use of `XMLHttpRequest` object.

And by `XMLHttpRequest` object you can't send file stream back to the server. There are some ways to imitate that though.

Also, at server-side, you should use `HttpPostedFileBase` class, to get the file stream back to the server.